# Wamp does not show anything when i trying to open my site on localhost

Tags: magento, localhost, wampserver

I am new to magento. Please help me how to show my site.
When i type in url : localhost/magento/projectname/  then it returns blank page.
How to solve this problem?
Any help will be appriciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May this work

select * from core_config_data where path = 'web/unsecure/base_url';

select * from core_config_data where path = 'web/secure/base_url';

Please use this queries and change the path of localhost up to your root directory for e.g 127.0.0.5/yourdirectorypath/

pls change accordingly...

also in index file make error true and in your root directory there is one error directory in that you will find error.xml.sample remove .sample and check what correction required....

Comment: Thank you Vijay. I am trying to do this. Thanks again.